# How to select a non-descendant on css

Tags: css

I want to select a non-descendant element with css on hover. To be more precise, when I hover on the image with `id="tapas"`, I want to change the visibility of the text with `id="cuerpo"`.

```
<div id="tapa">
    <div class="imgagenes">
        <img src="img/tapas.jpg" id="tapas">
        <img src="img/tapitas.jpg" id="tapitas">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p id="cuerpo">
            There is text here
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some time before I had the text in the same div, with `id="imgagenes"`, but I don't want that right now. Therefore, I had this command on css:

```
#tapas:hover ~ p {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: it can't work because the paragraph is not a sibling `~` of #tapas. In order to work either you change the structure of the markup or you need to use javascript. In CSS only it could work if you hover the element `.imgagenes`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators It is not possible to do this with CSS.